# sparklyr AnalysisException when creating two columns with mutate and lag

Tags: r, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

I have the following data.frame:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
testDF <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
B = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80), 
C = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800), 
D = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000))
```

After creating it, I can copy it into Spark using [sparklyr](http://spark.rstudio.com/reference/sparklyr/latest/index.html).

```
testDFCopied <- copy_to(sc, testDF, "testDF", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Once it's created, I can `mutate` a column, creating another one using the function `lag`:

```
head(testDFCopied %>% dplyr::arrange(A) %>% dplyr::mutate(E = lag(A)), 10)
Source:   query [?? x 5]
Database: spark connection master=yarn app=sparklyr local=FALSE

      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10   100  1000   NaN
2     2    20   200  2000     1
3     3    30   300  3000     2
4     4    40   400  4000     3
5     5    50   500  5000     4
6     6    60   600  6000     5
7     7    70   700  7000     6
8     8    80   800  8000     7
```

The problem arises when I try to create more than one column with `mutate` and also using the function `lag`. For instance, here I want to create two new columns, E and F, which are "lags" of the columns A and B:

```
head(testDFCopied %>% dplyr::arrange(A) %>% dplyr::mutate(E = lag(A), F = lag(B)), 10)
Source:   query [?? x 6]
Database: spark connection master=yarn app=sparklyr local=FALSE

Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW must match the required frame ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$$anonfun$apply$29$$anonfun$applyOrElse$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1785)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveWindowFrame$$anonfun$apply$29$$anonfun$applyOrElse$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:278)
```

However, this exception is not raised if I create two columns but I use `lag` just one time, for example:

```
head(testDFCopied %>% dplyr::arrange(A) %>% dplyr::mutate(E = lag(A), F = C - B), 10)
Source:   query [?? x 6]
Database: spark connection master=yarn app=sparklyr local=FALSE

      A     B     C     D     E     F
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10   100  1000   NaN    90
2     2    20   200  2000     1   180
3     3    30   300  3000     2   270
4     4    40   400  4000     3   360
5     5    50   500  5000     4   450
6     6    60   600  6000     5   540
7     7    70   700  7000     6   630
8     8    80   800  8000     7   720
```

For some reason, the exception is raised just when two `lag()` calls are executed within the `mutate` action. I've tried (unsuccessfully) different combinations of `lag()` and `lead()` and different arrangements of `mutate`. All of them raise the same exception, which I don't understand. Looking in the Spark code, I can see that the exception is raised here:

```
  /**
   * Check and add proper window frames for all window functions.
   */
  object ResolveWindowFrame extends Rule[LogicalPlan] {
    def apply(plan: LogicalPlan): LogicalPlan = plan transform {
      case logical: LogicalPlan => logical transformExpressions {
        case WindowExpression(wf: WindowFunction,
        WindowSpecDefinition(_, _, f: SpecifiedWindowFrame))
          if wf.frame != UnspecifiedFrame && wf.frame != f =>
          failAnalysis(s"Window Frame $f must match the required frame ${wf.frame}")
...
```

I understand that it should be related to some condition of the window function `lag` which fails to check, but I don't really understand the underlying problem here. Any help/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of spark are you using? I was able to run your examples with no issues. I'm running spark 2.1.0 and sparklyr 0.5.3-9002. As a side note, I was running into a similar issue using lag with spark 2.0.0 and sparklyr. Upgrading to spark 2.1.0 solved my problems.

Comment: @DDT-Actuary Thanks for your comment. I'm using Spark 2.0 and sparklyr 0.5.1. I'll update to spark 2.1 and try the same examples.